# how to use converters in numpy to change time string into number

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, numpy

I'm using `np.loadtxt`, and I want to convert an array containing values such as `13:39:58.495`, to seconds. My code is below.

```
from numpy import*
import time
from matplotlib.dates import datestr2num

time, W, L = loadtxt('file.txt', converters = {0: datestr2num})
```

this returns time values in the form of `735927.56942703`, which I'm not sure what units this is in terms of, hours minutes... I just want to convert the above time format to seconds. Thanks

Comment: What format is 13:39:58.495 in?

Comment: If you have a base time (a time that you know that the time strings in the file are not before that), then you can make a DateTime object of it and then by subtracting your DateTime objects in the file from the base DateTime object and using .total_seconds() function on the result of subtraction, you will get the difference in seconds.

Comment: What I want to do is to input an array containing times  in the format: 13:39:58.495 (hour:minute:second:miliscecond). But numpy won't let me input this without converting these values to a number. I want to convert them to seconds by taking the first value as 0 seconds, and the other values as the difference in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *converter* here is a function that accepts a string with possibly missing value and returns a float. If you want that float to be the number of seconds since the first entry; you could use a callable object to store the first value:

```
from datetime import datetime

class SecondsSinceFirst:
    def __init__(self, default=float('nan')):
        self.first = None
        self.default = default
    def __call__(self, value):
        value = value.decode('ascii', 'ignore').strip()
        if not value:  # no value
            return self.default
        try:  # specify input format here
            current = datetime.strptime(value, "%H:%M:%S.%f")
        except ValueError:  # can't parse the value
            return self.default
        else:
            if self.first is not None: 
                return (current - self.first).total_seconds()
            else:
                self.first = current
                return 0.0
```

Example:

```
>>> from io import BytesIO
>>> import numpy
>>> f = BytesIO(b"12:00:00.0 1 2\n12:30:00.0 3 4\n13:39:58.495 5 6")
>>> time, W, L = numpy.loadtxt(f, converters={0: SecondsSinceFirst()}, unpack=True)
>>> time
 array([    0.   ,  1800.   ,  5998.495]
```

Answer (score 0):

`datestr2num` is actually not on the docs, but is implemented as a wrapper to `date2num`. The [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.date2num) says:

> Return value is a floating point number (or sequence of floats) which gives the number of days (fraction part represents hours, minutes, seconds) since 0001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, plus one.